# Рекурсивный проход и подключение файлов с помощью LOVE2D

Tags: lua

Имеется папка `include`, лежащая рядом с `*.love`-файлом и содержащая в себе другие папки, которые в свою очередь могут содержать файл `meta.lua`. Как организовать проход этих папок и подключение@выполнение этого файла?

Comment: я подключаю скрипты при помощи dofile
к примеру dofile scripts//anAL.lua

Answer (score 2):

Я использую библиотеку lua-path. Она использует LuaFileSystem. Так что можно использовать только ее.

```
local path = require "path"

path.each('meta.lua', function(p)
  local fn = assert(loadstring(p))
  fn()
end, {recurse=true})
```

Comment: А можно получить документацию?

Comment: Все что есть можно найти на https://github.com/moteus/lua-path.

Comment: Странно... Не могу вызвать половину функций. Даже из вашего примера выдаёт: `attempt to call field 'each' (a nil value)`

Comment: Для Lua 5.1 нужно установить bit32.

Comment: Так в этом вся проблема. Тогда LOVE2D не смржет запускать библиотеку, ведь у него свой парсер, а не системный. Поэтому мне и нужно было решение на чистом Lua.
Я взял саму библиотеку и положил её в папку с проектом, ну функции вызвать не смог

Comment: Только что скачал Love 0.10.1. Он идет с lua51.dll (LuaJIT 2.0.4). Она использует runtime от Visual Studio 2013. Так что можно скомпилировать LuaFileSystem и bit32 с Lua 5.1. Желательно компоновать с msvcrt120. Но думаю любая версия должно работать.

Comment: Во-первых, я не использую Visual Studio.
Во-вторых, у меня не Windows.
В-третьих, да мне проще очередной велосипед изобрести, чем со всем этим заморачиваться.
И на этом спасибо!

Comment: Если Love использует LuaJIT, то можно попробовать использовать библиотеку ljsyscall (если она поддерживает твою ОС). Но я правда не вижу проблему в том что бы установить lfs используя тот же LuaRocks и использовать ее из Love.

Comment: Стоит попробовать. Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Можно провести рекурсию с использованием встроенной библиотеки  [ex](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ExtensionProposal)

```
    require 'ex'

    local function CheckDir(curpath,d)
         local fullname = (curpath.."\\"..d.name):gsub("\\$","")
         print(fullname)
          for entry in os.dir(fullname) do
              if entry["type"]=="directory" then  CheckDir(fullname, entry)    end
              if entry["type"]=="file" then
                      if entry.name=="meta.lua" then    assert(loadfile( fullname .."\\" ..entry.name)) ()  
                       end
              end
           end  
    end

    local pathname = os.currentdir()
    local init = { ["type"]="directory", name="" }
    CheckDir( pathname, init )
```

В 5.1 лежит тут ..\Lua\5.1\clibs\ex.dll